# Inserting the result of mysql_query() into the same database

Tags: php, mysql

Still learning PHP. I just hit a brick and need some quick help. Never handled this before. I have the php code below: I just need to automate a process. My intention is to select data from a holding table, do some manipulation on it and then insert the data into a permanent table in the same database.  So a user can click a hyperlink and the script does this for him. My problem is how to exploit the result from the first query in the php script below hence the outcome of the jargons you would below.  If you understand me, how can I do the insertion? Thanks

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';
$sql =  "SELECT nmea, rmc_time, signal, ROUND((FLOOR(latitude/ 100) + (latitude - 100   * FLOOR(latitude/ 100)) / 60), 5), north, ROUND((FLOOR(longitude / 100) + (longitude - 100 * FLOOR(longitude / 100)) / 60), 5), east, speed, track_angle, str_to_date( rmc_date, '%d%m%y' ) FROM server_imports";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
 if (!$result) {
  die("Query to convert and insert failed");
 }
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO server_main(server_nmea, server_rmc_time, signal, server_latitude, north, server_longitude, east, speed, track_angle, server_rmc_date");

 }
 echo "Data conversion and insertion completed";
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking for the correct INSERT INTO syntax?

Comment: If you just want to shovel data from one table to another, I'd suggest that you use a *one* query to do that, using f.e. the `INSERT INTO blabla (SELECT * FROM blibli)` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily combine the two :

```
INSERT INTO server_main(server_nmea, server_rmc_time, signal, server_latitude, 
north, server_longitude, east, speed, track_angle, server_rmc_date)
SELECT nmea, rmc_time, signal, 
ROUND((FLOOR(latitude/ 100) + (latitude - 100   * FLOOR(latitude/ 100)) / 60), 5), north, 
ROUND((FLOOR(longitude / 100) + (longitude - 100 * FLOOR(longitude / 100)) / 60), 5), east,
speed, track_angle, str_to_date( rmc_date, '%d%m%y' ) 
FROM server_imports
```

Comment: That is what I think I did at first but the records returned were few

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it all in one step:

```
INSERT INTO server_main(server_nmea, server_rmc_time, signal, 
  server_latitude, north, server_longitude, 
  east, speed, track_angle, server_rmc_date) 
SELECT nmea, rmc_time, signal, 
  ROUND((FLOOR(latitude/ 100) + (latitude - 100   * FLOOR(latitude/ 100)) / 60), 5),
  north, ROUND((FLOOR(longitude / 100) + (longitude - 100 * FLOOR(longitude / 100)) / 60), 5), 
  east, speed, track_angle, 
  str_to_date( rmc_date, '%d%m%y' ) 
FROM server_imports;
```

Comment: That is what I think I did at first but the records returned were few

Comment: @ibiangalex:  So how many records are returned by the SELECT statement alone? And what do they look like?  If the data types are not matching your target fields consistently or if you are selecting identical rows such that a target table UNIQUE KEY constraint will be violated, you won't be able to insert as many rows as you select.

Comment: Thanks dnagirl, 45 out of 100 were returned. It was just a sample data at first. Your point is right, I had to remove the indexes before doing the insertion. Because of the nature of the data, there would certainly be duplicates which I do not know how to handle while doing the insertion with the php script. I do know that I could remove the duplicates after. Many thanks for your useful opinion.

Comment: @ibiangalex: you don't need to remove the indices.  You have several choices. Have a look at `SELECT DISTINCT`, `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query. Just `INSERT` the rows you get with your existing `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO [...] SELECT [...]
```

Check out [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for more details.